# NetworkManager and dnsmasq dhcp address range

Tags: networkmanager, dnsmasq

Running Xubuntu 16.04 here. 
My problem is that `dnsmasq`, as started by NetworkManager, ignores the `dnsmasq.conf` files in `/etc/dnsmasq`, `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`, and `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d`.  Instead, NetworkManager starts `dnsmasq` with this command:

```
9949 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file --no-hosts --keep-in-foreground --bind-interfaces --except-interface=lo --clear-on-reload --strict-order --listen-address=10.42.0.1 --dhcp-range=10.42.0.10,10.42.0.254,60m --dhcp-option=option:router,10.42.0.1 --dhcp-lease-max=50 --pid-file=/var/run/nm-dnsmasq-wlan1.pid --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d
```

I can find nowhere on my system where an address range of `10.42.0.10,10.42.0.254,60m` is specified.

Where is this coming from???

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` or `/etc/dnsmasq`? Looks like the manual expects the former. A restart would be necessary of the service after a change as well.

Comment: Yup, I have /etc/dnsmasq.conf.  And /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf.  Both are ignored.  And yes, there have been several system restarts.

Comment: I believe that the problems is caused by the "--conf-file  (blank)" directive being issued by NetworkManager when it starts dnsmasq.  How can I remove this directive from the command line that NetworkManager is issuing?  Apparently a test that NetworkManager is performing is not working properly:

strings /usr/sbin/NetworkManager|grep conf_file
conf_file != NULL

Comment: On my system dnsmasq is not being started by init, but by NetworkManager. NetworkManager (a binary) is generating the command internally and (I believe) blowing it when checking for the definition of an environment variable called 'conf_file'.

Comment: Exporting "conf_file=dnsmasq.conf" in the NetworkManager startup script didn't work. Here's the two relevant lines from syslog: 

Oct 6 11:19:44 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[13278]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.101.50 -- 192.168.101.150, lease time 12h 
Oct 6 11:19:44 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[13278]: DHCP, IP range 10.42.0.10 -- 10.42.0.254, lease time 1h

Apparently, the environment variable was detected and used to produce the first line, which was immediately undone by the second line.

Comment: OK, got it.  direct from the source, file :  nm-dnsmasq-manager.c

Comment: /* dnsmasq may read from it's default config file location, which if that
          location is a valid config file, it will combine with the options her
e
          and cause undesirable side-effects.  Like sending bogus IP addresses
          as the gateway or whatever.  So tell dnsmasq not to use any config file at all.
         */

Comment: If your question is - how do I change the IP range you can update in `nm-connection-editor`, using `nmcli connection modify <CONN> ipv4.addresses`, or as pointed out in another answer by finding and editing the `*.nmconnection` file.  IF on the other had the question is about other parameters that do not conflict with the commandline you saw - I suspect this should be doable in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d` but since you tried to change what the commandline had it was ignored

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it. direct from the source, file : nm-dnsmasq-manager.c

/* dnsmasq may read from it's default config file location, which if that location is a valid config file, it will combine with the options here and cause undesirable side-effects. Like sending bogus IP addresses as the gateway or whatever. So tell dnsmasq not to use any config file at all. */

NetworkManager is jealous of dnsmasq configuration values, and will not allow outside interference with them.  NetworkManager internally builds and issues the command line that starts dnsmasq, and in doing so, includes the --conf-file (blank) directive, which prevents use of any user or system-supplied dnsmasq configuration file.

Comment: Explain it to me like I’m five years old — how does this answer the question? Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

**Context/Cause:** NetworkManager, being a Lennard Poettering project, is openly hostile towards Unixy things, and tries to replace GNU and call itself “*the* Linux”. Therefore, it shuns tried and tested principles like “everything is a file”. Leading to it offering command line interfaces for configuration, that are using some “automagical” state files in the back (because Linux is still Unixy, imagine that).

#### Intended solution

So the way it is *intended* to be configured, is to either

```bash
nmcli connection modify MyConnection ipv4.addresses 10.42.1.1/24 # Set the IP range here
nmcli connection up MyConnection # Restart the connection to apply it
```

Which, on Linux Mint, can be done via the GUI too, by editing the connection, and adding a line to the table below “Address(es)” in the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs. (Though this is confusing, and may result in merely assigning secondary addresses without removing the “automagic” one.)

#### Professional solution

Or we can just alter the files that these commands modify, and gain the ability to apply such changes even when we don’t want to execute anything. (Like when provisioning machines in a company network.) Which, on Linux Mint, would be:

```bash
vi /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyConnection.nmconnection # Or in my case, is just copy the file over from my central storage.
nmcli connection reload # Only necessary when there is no boot following
nmcli connection up MyConnection # ditto
```

#### Notes

In any case, replace `MyConnection` by the name of your connection, that you can find via `nmcli connection` or in the `id` field of the `[connection]` section of your `.nmconnection` file. (Note that the file name may escape some special characters and hence not be exactly the same. And if done manually, does not need to be the same *at all*.)

It seems e.g. `10.42.1.1/24` would set the server’s own IP to 10.42.1.1 and give the clients an IP in the range 10.42.1.2 to 10.42.1.254. I’d prefer it if the server’s IP could be set separately, but at least it does the job.

What I haven’t included here, is how to do it when you need to bridge two networks so they have the *same* IP range. (Like a laptop usually connecting via WIFI, but getting the same server IP address when connecting via Ethernet cable for speed.)